# PDFTable object is not working in ABC PDF

Tags: c#, abcpdf

https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2f4-examples%2f10-table2.htm

we are using ABC PDF v11. But we are not able to see PDFTable class which is in above url.

How do I enable PDFTable in my project? any reference should I add?

Comment: Perhaps this info is helpful: https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2f4-examples%2f10-table2.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ABC pdf in your local machine (https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-download.aspx)
2. Goto C:\Program Files\WebSupergoo\ABCpdf .NET 11.3 x64
3. Inside this you will find PDFTable project (C:\Program Files\WebSupergoo\ABCpdf .NET 11.3 x64\ExampleProjects\PDFTable)
4. Add PDFTable.cs in your project (PDFTable is not a default class)
5. Follow steps in https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2f4-examples%2f10-table2.htm